Wordpress woocommerce checkoutpage order total keeps loading
So my order total and payment options keeps loading on the woocomerce checkout page.
From what I was able to find online this is an AJAX related problem.
screenshot
I tried most of the things that I could find online to solve that already including swapping to the default theme and turning all the plugins off except woocomerce but it stays like this. I also checked my domain settings and they are correct. Memory limit is also set high enough.

In your case i bet its file permission issue , maybe firewall  or htaccess ? If you dont know how to check ask your hosting company.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
